# Screen Pulling up and down Ios Phonegap

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want make screen pull up and down in the IOS using Phonegap. I have used iscroll but didnt work for me. Please help how to do Screen Pull up and down with fixed header and footer.

first image show kayak application, the actual screen and in second image screen has pulled down and header is fixed. I want that way.

[image: actual screen is like below]

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I just wanted to know which setting do I required in Phonegap.or in the code. I am new in to the technology

Comment: You don't have to mess with any PhoneGap settings. You can create your static header and footer, then put a body in between that uses `overflow: scroll`, or if you want the webkit effect use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, then in that body put your list. You can do this all with HTML and CSS. This would obviously need some work as I threw it together really quickly, but are you trying to get something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3sgTk/)?

Comment: I did a quick fork of Andrews jsfiddle to fit the screen on mobile. Go to [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/whit1440/N97UY/3/show/) on an iPhone or iPhone sim to see it more like it would come in the actual app. Note that the touch scrolling won't work the same on your desktop browser.

Comment: @AndrewLively,  question has edited for more clarification. First is normal image and second is puled down.

Comment: @Sushant you get that effect when you use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` on touch devices. Just make sure on PhoneGap that you have `DisallowOverscroll` set to true in your config.xml file.

Comment: okk @AndrewLively, ill give a try and let you know. thank you very much!
I have checkd your fiddle, but it moves along with header and footer in browser

Comment: I want background as in grey color and i tried your fiddle code on iPhone but it pulled only once while scrolling. I want it can be pulled any time and background should be grey like default iPhone apps  have it normally.

Comment: The fiddle on the iPhone won't act quite the same as an app. It has to do with the `DisallowOverscroll` like @AndrewLively said, which won't be there in the fiddle. Scroll the inner body down first (by moving your touch up), then back up and it should look right.

Comment: Can you just tap on the header to show that screen  ---  example i made--- http://jsfiddle.net/Tvkq3/10/

Comment: @Tasos, no I dont need tap to pull screen down. I should be able to pull it down at the top or pull it up at bottom of page. You can check  contacts list in iPhone for this feature.

Comment: Ok i undestand. I found some demos for you that may help --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154489/ios-android-notification-center-with-jquery-drag-div-down-overlay ---  http://jsfiddle.net/JXeWA/46/  --- http://codepen.io/Edo_B/pen/cLbrt